# My Report keeps executing for ever - how can I debug the SQL that is being executed?

Tags: reporting-services

I have report that has been working fine for a long time, now after a re-deploy of the same report (no changes made) it have all the sudden become unable to finish the execution.

For debugging I have removed all content from the report, so that only the header, footer, dataset's and parameters are left.

Then I modified the DataSet one by one to only return dummy data without actually querying the database.
By doing so the DataSet which caused the execution to hang forever was identified.

To further debug this issue, I copied the SQL from this DataSet into MS SQL Management Studio and here it executes without any problems - so the SQL seems fine.
So what could be the difference here and are there any good advice on how to debug this?

Could it be related to the tempDb, expecting that reporting service is using ReportServerTempDB and MS SQL Management Studio is using tempdb.

Comment: Have a read about Parameter sniffing and using the Option Recompile in your datasets. I've had this issue and have been able to rectify it using the same.